How to get the filename of the generated PDF file using Microsoft Print to PDF
I'm printing text using essentially the "Microsoft Print to PDF" printer. This works fine, there are no issues with the generated PDF file whatsoever.
However I'd like to get the full path of the PDF file the user has chosen and I have no idea how.

The user clicks on OK and the file chooser is shown:

Ths user chooses a PDF filename/path and the PDF file is created correctly.
Now the only problem I have is I have no idea where the PDF is created as the user can choose any folder he wants.
Questions:

Is it possible to get the full path of the file the user has chosen/created?
Nice to have: is it possible to set the initial folder that is shown to the user? By default it is the user's "Documents" folder.

This are the essential parts of the code.
...
CPrintDialog printDlg(FALSE, PD_ALLPAGES | PD_USEDEVMODECOPIES | PD_NOPAGENUMS | PD_NOSELECTION);

// ask the user to select a printer
if (printDlg.DoModal() == IDCANCEL)
   return FALSE;

CDC m_dc;
// Attach a printer DC
if (!m_dc.Attach(printDlg.GetPrinterDC()))
  return FALSE;
...

m_dc.StartPage();
...
m_pDC->DrawText(...
...
m_dc.EndDoc();


Provide the file name yourself, grab the file, then display a bogus FileSave dialog to the user to rename the already printed file as something else?

@GSerg I'm not quite sure I understood your comment, could you elaborate a bit more?

When you initiate a print operation programmatically, you have the option to pre-populate the file name in case the printing is to a file. Pre-populate the file name with a temporary file name. Print. Now you have the file and you know where it is. Then display the FileSave dialog for the user and copy that temporary file as what the user has selected.

Can you not also flip the order a bit? Display a "fake" FileSave dialog for the user, get the filename but do not place a file there, then call the print operation with the filename you just got.

If the information isn't immediately available through a public interface you can install a WinEvents hook and collect the data from the subsequent "Save As..." dialog.

@GSerg I'll try that, it sounds promising. Right now I don't know where to pre-populate the file name, but I'll find out...

What type of data are you trying to print to PDF? I ask because WebView2 has a native print to pdf feature which sounds right up your street.

@AndrewTruckle WebView2 is not an option. I'm printing text.

The CPrintDialog is not the one prompting the user for the PDF filename.  That actually happens when you call m_dc.StartDoc() with "FILE:" as the output file.  By then, it is too late to retrieve the filename since the printing process has already begun.
The documentation for the PRINTDLG struct says:

Flags
Type: DWORD
Initializes the Print dialog box. When the dialog box returns, it sets these flags to indicate the user's input. This member can be one or more of the following values.



Value
Meaning




...
...


PD_PRINTTOFILE0x00000020
If this flag is set, the Print to File check box is selected. If this flag is set when the PrintDlg function returns, the offset indicated by the wOutputOffset member of the DEVNAMES structure contains the string "FILE:". When you call the StartDoc function to start the printing operation, specify this "FILE:" string in the lpszOutput member of the DOCINFO structure. Specifying this string causes the print subsystem to query the user for the name of the output file.


...
...




So, to do what you are asking for, you need to detect when the CPrintDialog has selected the "Microsoft Print to PDF" printer (or when printDlg.GetPortName() returns "FILE:"), and then use your own CFileDialog to prompt the user for the PDF filename, and then you can pass that filename in the DOCINFO that you give to m_dc.StartDoc(), avoiding the system prompt.

That sounds promising. I'll give it a try.
